# Make ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor View Engine ignore .vbhtml files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I remove the VB Razor Engine or configure the RazorViewEngine to not use and look for .vbhtml files on disk? For new ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor projects, I always remove the WebFormViewEngine in Application_Start because I won't ever be using it and so I don't need it to search for .aspx, .ascx or .master files on disk. For this same reason I would like to avoid .vbhtml file searching.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the code for your custom view engine:

```
public class CSRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine {

    public CSRazorViewEngine() {

        base.AreaViewLocationFormats = new string[] { 
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };

        base.AreaMasterLocationFormats = new string[] { 
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };

        base.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { 
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };

        base.ViewLocationFormats = new string[] {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };

        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };

        base.MasterLocationFormats = new string[] {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };

        base.FileExtensions = new string[] { "cshtml" };
    }
}
```

Register this on Application_Start method like this:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CSRazorViewEngine());
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `FileExtensions` property be set as well?  `base.FileExtensions = new string[] { "cshtml" };`

Answer (score 12):

Why is there no point in removing search in `.vbhtml` if I'm never going to use it?

Here is how I do it (but I still don't know is it a good thing to remove vbhtml):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine().DisableVbhtml());

    ...
}
```

Extension method code:

```
public static RazorViewEngine DisableVbhtml(this RazorViewEngine engine)
{
    engine.AreaViewLocationFormats = FilterOutVbhtml(engine.AreaViewLocationFormats);
    engine.AreaMasterLocationFormats = FilterOutVbhtml(engine.AreaMasterLocationFormats);
    engine.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = FilterOutVbhtml(engine.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats);
    engine.ViewLocationFormats = FilterOutVbhtml(engine.ViewLocationFormats);
    engine.MasterLocationFormats = FilterOutVbhtml(engine.MasterLocationFormats);
    engine.PartialViewLocationFormats = FilterOutVbhtml(engine.PartialViewLocationFormats);
    engine.FileExtensions = FilterOutVbhtml(engine.FileExtensions);

    return engine;
}

private static string[] FilterOutVbhtml(string[] source)
{
    return source.Where(s => !s.Contains("vbhtml")).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no point in doing this.

However, if you really want to, you can clear `ViewEngines`, then register your own `RazorViewEngine` with `FileExtensions` set to `".cshtml"`.

Comment: No point? Surely if you aren't using VB then it's low cost speed performance to do this. Also saves unnecessary File.Exists() lookups. Is it really that insignificant?

Comment: Actually it is insignificant because since at least version 3, the VirtualPathProvider caches located views.

Comment: @ErikPhilips But when and you're presented with a giant list of locations searched when a view couldn't be found, it wastes your time and energy to look through a bunch of meaningless entries. This is about tidying up error messages, not necessarily about performance.

Answer (score 7):

I figured I'd merge the examples from @tugberk and @Dimps:

```
public class CSHtmlRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine {
    public CSHtmlRazorViewEngine()
        : base() {
        this.AreaMasterLocationFormats = Filter(base.AreaMasterLocationFormats);
        this.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = Filter(base.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats);
        this.AreaViewLocationFormats = Filter(base.AreaViewLocationFormats);
        this.FileExtensions = Filter(base.FileExtensions);
        this.MasterLocationFormats = Filter(base.MasterLocationFormats);
        this.PartialViewLocationFormats = Filter(base.PartialViewLocationFormats);
        this.ViewLocationFormats = Filter(base.ViewLocationFormats);
    }

    private static string[] Filter(
        string[] source) {
        return source.Where(
            s =>
                s.Contains("cshtml")).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A summary from above with a single class.

Use it like this:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new FilteredRazorViewEngine("cshtml"));
```

Class:

```
public class FilteredRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    private string _extension;

    public FilteredRazorViewEngine(string viewTypeExtension)
        : base()
    {
        _extension = viewTypeExtension;

        AreaMasterLocationFormats = Filter(base.AreaMasterLocationFormats);
        AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = Filter(base.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats);
        AreaViewLocationFormats = Filter(base.AreaViewLocationFormats);
        FileExtensions = Filter(base.FileExtensions);
        MasterLocationFormats = Filter(base.MasterLocationFormats);
        PartialViewLocationFormats = Filter(base.PartialViewLocationFormats);
        ViewLocationFormats = Filter(base.ViewLocationFormats);
    }

    private string[] Filter(string[] source)
    {
        return source.Where(
            s =>
                s.Contains(_extension)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12591992/1037948), combining and extending previous solutions.

Just in case you want to specify extensions for other ViewEngines, inherit from the 'original' and either build or filter (your preference, I just thought filtering seemed more work than starting a fresh list).

#### Usage:

```
// custom extension(s)
ViewEngines.Engines.UseOnly(new ExtensionSpecificRazorViewEngine("cshtml"));
ViewEngines.Engines.UseOnly(new ExtensionSpecificRazorViewEngine("myhtml", "xhtml"));

// filtered from original extensions
ViewEngines.Engines.UseOnly(new ExtensionSpecificRazorViewEngine(false, "cshtml", "vbhtml"));
```

#### Engine-specific:

```
/// <summary>
/// Razor View Engine only expecting the specified extensions
/// </summary>
public class ExtensionSpecificRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public ExtensionSpecificRazorViewEngine(params string[] extensions) : this(true, extensions) { }

    public ExtensionSpecificRazorViewEngine(bool isBuildOrFilter, params string[] extensions) : this(null, isBuildOrFilter, extensions) {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new ViewEngine only expecting the provided extension
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="viewPageActivator"></param>
    /// <param name="isBuildOrFilter"></param>
    /// <param name="extensions"></param>
    public ExtensionSpecificRazorViewEngine(IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator, bool isBuildOrFilter, params string[] extensions)
        : base(viewPageActivator)
    {
        if (isBuildOrFilter) this.BuildSpecifically(extensions);
        else this.FilterSpecifically(extensions);

        this.FileExtensions = extensions;
    }
}//---  class   ExtensionSpecificRazorViewEngine
```

#### Which uses:

```
/// <summary>
/// Because classes can't inherit from multiple classes, we put the build/filter logic in a helper
/// that's used by the ViewEngine implementation which inherits from RazorViewEngine or WebFormViewEngine, etc
/// </summary>
public static class ExtensionSpecificViewEngineExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Given a collection of ViewEngines, clear them and add the indicated engine</para>
    /// <example>ex) <code>ViewEngines.Engines.UseOnly(new RazorViewEngine());</code></example>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="engines">list of available engines</param>
    /// <param name="engine">the only engine to use</param>
    public static void UseOnly(this ViewEngineCollection engines, IViewEngine engine)
    {
        engines.Clear();
        engines.Add(engine);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Build the lookup paths specifically for the indicated extension(s)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="engine"></param>
    /// <param name="extensions"></param>
    public static void BuildSpecifically(this BuildManagerViewEngine engine, string[] extensions)
    {
        engine.AreaMasterLocationFormats =      Build(extensions, "~/Areas/{2}");
        engine.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = Build(extensions, "~/Areas/{2}");
        engine.AreaViewLocationFormats =        Build(extensions, "~/Areas/{2}");
        engine.FileExtensions =                 Build(extensions);
        engine.MasterLocationFormats =          Build(extensions);
        engine.PartialViewLocationFormats =     Build(extensions);
        engine.ViewLocationFormats =            Build(extensions);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Filter the existing, default extensions from the view engine's lookup paths for the indicated extensions
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="engine"></param>
    /// <param name="extensions"></param>
    public static void FilterSpecifically(this BuildManagerViewEngine engine, string[] extensions)
    {
        engine.AreaMasterLocationFormats =      Filter(extensions, engine/*base*/.AreaMasterLocationFormats);
        engine.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = Filter(extensions, engine/*base*/.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats);
        engine.AreaViewLocationFormats =        Filter(extensions, engine/*base*/.AreaViewLocationFormats);
        engine.FileExtensions =                 Filter(extensions, engine/*base*/.FileExtensions);
        engine.MasterLocationFormats =          Filter(extensions, engine/*base*/.MasterLocationFormats);
        engine.PartialViewLocationFormats =     Filter(extensions, engine/*base*/.PartialViewLocationFormats);
        engine.ViewLocationFormats =            Filter(extensions, engine/*base*/.ViewLocationFormats);
    }

    private static string[] Build(string[] extensions, string prefix = "~")
    {
        return extensions.SelectMany(x => new[] {
                prefix + "/Views/{1}/{0}." + x,
                prefix + "/Views/Shared/{0}." + x
            }).ToArray();
    }

    private static string[] Filter(string[] extensions, params string[] source)
    {
        return source.Where(s => extensions.Any(s.EndsWith)).ToArray();
    }
}//---  class   ExtensionSpecificViewEngineExtensions
```

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta when you explain what to fix I'd be happy to, because it works just fine for me.  what 'usage scenario' are you trying?  what code are you attempting?

Answer (score 1):

This one keeps the original `RazorViewEngine` and cleans away the VB extensions.

```
//Remove the legacy ASPX view engine
ViewEngines.Engines.Remove(ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<WebFormViewEngine>().Single());

//Remove VB from the remaining view engine
var target = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().Single();
(new Expression<Func<RazorViewEngine,string[]>>[] {
    y => y.FileExtensions,
    y => y.ViewLocationFormats,
    y => y.PartialViewLocationFormats,
    y => y.MasterLocationFormats,
    y => y.AreaMasterLocationFormats,
    y => y.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats,
    y => y.AreaViewLocationFormats
}
).Select(y => (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)y.Body).Member).ToList()
    .ForEach(y => y.SetValue(target,((string[])y.GetValue(target))
    .Where(x => x.EndsWith("cshtml")).ToArray(),null));
```