# MVC 3 Razor - How to stop the view engine from searching the aspx and ascx pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I had a small bug in a view and noticed that the view engine was searching not only for my razor views but for aspx/ascx pages. (My bug is fixed)

Is there a way to tell it to only search the Razor view engine?

Here is the error message that was displayed:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Areas/BO/Views/Organization/Index.aspx
~/Areas/BO/Views/Organization/Index.ascx
~/Areas/BO/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Areas/BO/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Organization/Index.aspx
~/Views/Organization/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Areas/BO/Views/Organization/Index.cshtml
~/Areas/BO/Views/Organization/Index.vbhtml
~/Areas/BO/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Areas/BO/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Organization/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Organization/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to remove the `WebFormsViewEngine` from `ViewEngine.Engines` so that it only contains a `RazorViewEngine`.

For example:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

Comment: I would put this at app_start?

Comment: Anyway to also remove .vbhtml?

Comment: @Eddie: Set the `RazorViewEngine`'s `FileExtensions` to `new[] { "cshtml" }`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - first two lines in `Application_Start()`: `ViewEngines.Engines.Clear(); ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine { FileExtensions = new[] { "cshtml" } });`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a desire to use custom extensions in your ViewEngines, and the suggestion to set the `ViewEngine.FileExtensions = new[] { "cshtml" }` doesn't work for you either, check out the related question: [Make ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor View Engine ignore .vbhtml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049445/make-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view-engine-ignore-vbhtml-files/20912185#20912185)

Specifically my answer (or the others really) https://stackoverflow.com/a/20912185/1037948