# Html.Partial searches for aspx instead of cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view where i try to include a partial with the following code:

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_LatestLog")
</div>
```

It results in an error with the following message

```
Message:  The partial view '_LatestLog.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Areas/Primary/Views/PrimaryPersonnelRoleWithAuthority/_LatestLog.aspx
~/Areas/Primary/Views/PrimaryPersonnelRoleWithAuthority/_LatestLog.ascx
~/Areas/Primary/Views/Shared/_LatestLog.aspx
~/Areas/Primary/Views/Shared/_LatestLog.ascx
~/Views/PrimaryPersonnelRoleWithAuthority/_LatestLog.aspx
```

I expected it to find the file _LatestLog.cshtml in the same folder, what ever could be wrong?

Comment: the error meant to say that the following locations were searched and your page `not found`. Check your have proper files in the proper directory.

Comment: The weird thing is that it's looking for files with an extension of "aspx" or "ascx", not the "cshtml" i am expecting when running an MVC4-project.

Comment: really? check it again :D btw, its also searching cshtml files which you can see in your message

Comment: It tries to locate the file for all available view engines. Just like Razor, it looks for files with ASPX as well.. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727259/mvc-3-razor-how-to-stop-the-view-engine-from-searching-the-aspx-and-ascx-pages) post. You can remove the aspx view engine.

Comment: Check the runtime value of the following statement: `ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().Single().FileExtensions`

Comment: It was the custom built logger we used that cut down the error message so i didn't see the cshtml files being searched and as Mukul Joshi down below pointed out it wasn't in the Primary Area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the `_LatestLog` partial view is not available in the `Primary` area.

You can do 3 things here:

- create a partial view in that primary area;
- create a partial view in shared;
- or you can keep a partial view in some other area and call that partial view by giving path like:

  ```
  @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Primary/Views/PrimaryPersonnelRoleWithAuthority/_LatestLog.cshtml")
  ```

Answer (score 4):

If you want your view engine to search only for Razor files add this in app_start

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```