# Process .html in ASP.NET razor as .cshtml

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

Is it possible to process .html files like .cshtml files in asp.net razor?

I want to use Webstorm and VS side by side. (Webstorm for html and js stuff and VS for the c# stuff)

Comment: Cant webstorm handle the cshtml?! Or can you not set a flag to say treat cshtml the same as html?!

Comment: Define "process". Can you show relevant code for how you wish to use this?

Comment: by process I mean that the included inline c# code is executed. Webstorm does not parse .cshtml

Comment: Still unclear. Do you mean that in `HomeController`'s `Index()` method you want to `return View();`, which should render `~/Views/Home/Index.html`?

Comment: yes. it also should process the inline c# code in the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Razor engine only looks for `.cshtml` and `.vbhtml` files. You can change this behavior by defining a custom ViewEngine inheriting from `RazorViewEngine` and adding locations to search for views.

From [Make ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor View Engine ignore .vbhtml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049445/make-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view-engine-ignore-vbhtml-files):

```
public class CSRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine {

    public CSRazorViewEngine() {

        base.AreaViewLocationFormats = new string[] { 
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.html",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.html",
        };

        base.AreaMasterLocationFormats = new string[] { 
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.html",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.html",
        };

        base.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { 
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.html",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.html",
        };

        base.ViewLocationFormats = new string[] {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.html",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.html",
        };

        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.html",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.html",
        };

        base.MasterLocationFormats = new string[] {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.html",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.html",
        };

        base.FileExtensions = new[]
        {
            "cshtml",
            "html",
        };
    }
}
```

Then register it in your `Application_Start()`:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CSRazorViewEngine());
```

Or just [add `.cshtml` to your Webstorm's configuration as File Type HTML](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#create).